# getting error in this code of checking palindrome string neglecting punctuation marks

Tags: c, palindrome

I am writing a code for checking whether the string is palindrome or not.I want to neglect spaces and punctuation marks or any other non alphabetic character.
which basically means "madam 'I     Imadam" should be a palindrome as well according to my code.
But not getting the appropriate result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void chkpalindrome(char []);
int main()
{
    char s[50];
    gets(s);
    chkpalindrome(s);
    return 0;
}
void chkpalindrome(char a[50])
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int flag=1;
    while(a[j+1]!='\0') //so that 'j' should point to the last index                         of string
    {
        j=j+1;
    }
    while((i!=j)&&(i!=(j+1)))
    {
        if((a[i]<'A')||('Z'<a[i]<'a')||(a[i]>'z'))
        { 
            i=i+1; 
        }
        else if((a[j]<'A')||('Z'<a[j]<'a')||(a[j]>'z'))
        {
            j=j-1;
        }
        else
        {
        if(a[i]!=a[j])
        {
            flag=0;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            i=i+1;
            j=j-1;
        }
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {
        printf("IT IS A PALINDROME");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("IT IS NOT A PALINDROME");
    }
}
```

Expected results-madam I'   Imadam  -IT IS A PALINDROME
evee-it is not a palindrome
But actual results are coming out to be every string as a palindrome

Comment: First of all avoid magic numbers, e.g. instead of `65` use `'A'` etc.

Comment: @Jabberwocky did it..still facing the same issue

Comment: That's not the reason of the bug, it just makes the code easier to read and thus easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form `90<a[i]<97` is interpreted as `(90<a[i])<97`, so of course this is not what you expected

Must be `(90<a[i]) && (a[i]<97)`

You have several times that error

And as it was said in remarks use char like 'a' rather than the code

---

rather than to do

```
while(a[j+1]!='\0') //so that 'j' should point to the last index                         of string
{
    j=j+1;
}
```

I encourage you to use *strlen*

Comment: Even better than fixing this as `if((a[i]<'A') || (('Z'<a[i]) && (a[i]<'a')) || (a[i]>'z'))` would be `if(!isalpha((int)a[i]))`. There is one difference: Depending on your locale setting, `isalpha()` may classify other characters like `é` as alphabetic characters.

Comment: @Bodo to use _isalpha_ is not compatible with the original program because you change its behavior, but this is a good remarks and that can interest the OP

Comment: Using `isalpha` may change the behavior of the original program, but should do exactly what the text of the question states: _I want to neglect spaces and punctuation marks or any other non alphabetic character._

Comment: @Bodo this is why I said "this is a good remarks and that can interest the OP" ;-)